# drag and drop with easeljs

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, drag-and-drop, easeljs

I apologize that is isn't strictly a coding question. Has anyone come across a good BASIC  tutorial explaining how to drag things in Easeljs? I've been experimenting with jQuery Mobile and the 'touch punch' plugin in the DOM for an app I'm developing and it works great. All devices, all browsers. But i recently read that phonegap totally sucks so I'm trying to get the same effects in Canvas for Cocoonjs.

But I can't seem to get anything working in Canvas. I've scoured the web and it seems everyone just reuses Easeljs' daisy example.

Has anyone found a good, simple, clear example without all the extra BS?
Thanks in advance. And again I apologize this isn't a coding question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm getting this correctly, you are trying to use jQuery for Drag&Drop on canvas?
If that is the case, then the simple answer is: It's not possible. (at least not out of the box, and making this work would take way too much effort and would make no sense)

Other than that you have pretty much answered your question yourself, the EaselJS Daisy DragAndDrop Example from here: https://github.com/CreateJS/EaselJS/tree/master/examples already is like a perfect example - unfortunately it won't get much simpler than that.

Comment: thanks Olsn. I actually ended up playing with and breaking down the daisy example a little more, and learned some basics.

Comment: that's the way to go! keep doing that and you'll learn a lot in no time ;)